# when i used sed -n ,why this err about sed -n ' $j,4800p'

Tags: shell-script, sed

```
LINEnum=$(grep -nr "#32" IM_DlCtrlRef.txt | cut -d : -f 1)
for j in $LINEnum
do
    echo $j
    sed -n '$j,4800p'  IM_DlCtrlRef.txt >> IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
    for insertl in {1..4}
    do
        cat zero.txt >> IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
    done
done
```

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `j'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the script?

Comment: try `"$j,4800p"`

Comment: `sed -n '/#32/,4800p' IM_DlCtrlRef.txt >> IM_DlCtrlRef_bak`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem (the one that causes a syntax error) lies on the `sed` line:

```
sed -n '$j,4800p'  IM_DlCtrlRef.txt >> IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
```

You want to use the shell variable `$j` in you `sed` script as the start line number (the `sed` script extracts lines `$j` to 4800 out of a file), but you prevent the shell from expanding the variable by using single-quotes. This means that `sed` will get `$j` as the start address, which will confuse it no ends.

Simply change that line to have double-quotes instead.

Now, looking at the complete script:

```
LINEnum=$(grep -nr "#32" IM_DlCtrlRef.txt | cut -d : -f 1)
for j in $LINEnum
do
    echo $j
    sed -n "$j,4800p"  IM_DlCtrlRef.txt >> IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
    for insertl in {1..4}
        do
    cat zero.txt >> IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
        done
done
```

This has a few style issues and performance issues that you may or may not want to fix.

Firstly, you read in all line numbers into a variable. This is a waste of memory, but you need to do this because the `for`-loop needs to know exactly what to loop over.

Another solution would be to read the line numbers one by one:

```
grep -nr "#32" IM_DlCtrlRef.txt | cut -d : -f 1 |
while read j; do
   # ...
done
```

This means there's no limit to how much data the script is able to gulp in.

BTW, `-r` makes `grep` search recursively, so that's probably not needed here. Replace it with `-F` since you're looking for a fixed string (not a regular expression).

However, since you're only interested in line numbers of lines matching `#32`, you could replace that whole pipe with

```
sed -n '/#32/=' IM_DlCtrlRef.txt
```

The `sed` command `=` prints line numbers.

With a final round of touch-up, the script becomes

```
sed -n '/#32/=' IM_DlCtrlRef.txt |
while read j; do
    echo $j
    sed -n "$j,4800p" IM_DlCtrlRef.txt >>IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
    for insertl in {1..4}; do
        cat zero.txt >>IM_DlCtrlRef_bak
    done
done
```

Comment: @Mark, if you click to accept the answer the question is "formally" accepted. (and I get a bit of cred)

Comment: first time use this , I not find where/how I to click the accept button.  I will try it later, and thanks much.

Comment: @Mark under the up-vote/down-vote arrows to the left of the answer :-)